# c# .Net how do I get the path of the .exe shortcut?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I deployed my application through ClickOnce.

I created a shortcut of my application onto my desktop.

When I run the shortcut, my application simply displays its current location but is wrong. Its displaying the location of its actual installation but I want the location of where the shortcut is which in this case would be my desktop.

```
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));

        Console.ReadKey();
```

None of the above give me the location of the shortcut that I am running.

Comment: The directory specified in the "Start in" field of the shortcut will set the initial value of `GetCurrentDirectory()`. If not specified, then it is set to the directory that the EXE is run from. If you want the path of the shortcut itself, that path is available from the Win32 [`GetStartupInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230.aspx) function in the `STARTUPINFO.lpTitle` field when the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag is enabled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is that c++?

Comment: you can [use PInvoke to call `GetStartupInfo()` in C#](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getstartupinfo).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau your solution did not work because clickonce shortcuts are not of type .ink. They are application reference.

Comment: then you will probably not be able to obtain the path of the shortcut itself.